# Логика управления процессами

Tags: алгоритм

Добрый день.

Вопрос, возможно, плохо сформулирован, но пока у самого нет четкого понимания что и как надо сделать.

Что есть (уже написано, касательно данного вопроса): подсистема назначения в отслеживания выполнения задач (сродни стандартной TODO, типа RedMine) и система записи сообщений о событиях (грубо можно сравнить с Syslog).

Цель: сделать некоторую автоматизацию процессов на ферме. То есть если произошло какое-то событие (конкретное), автоматически создать некоторый набор задач.

Пример (на кроликах очень наглядно): Событие - случка кролихи. Через 15 дней надо провести дезинфекцию клетки, через 18 дней - пересадить в чистую клетку, через 30 дней - проведение прививок молодняку, через 60 дней - новая случка, через 80 дней забой молодняка.

Я изначально предполагал, что первоисточником (событием), которое будет порождать цепочки задач будет сообщение. Но сейчас вижу, что это совершенно не правильное решение. Сообщение - это конечная сущность в системе (по аналогии с Syslog), которая не должна становиться тригером для создания новых сущностей в системе.

Выход, который сейчас вижу в голове - создание новой сущности - "Событие", которое при создании будет генерировать цепочку задач. Но тут два момента: во-первых - пока не очень вижу как это реализовать (с точки зрения того, как это должно выглядеть), и, во-вторых, не очень хочется городить эту надстройку, если можно обойтись без нее.

Может кто сталкивался с чем-то похожим и может подсказать как лучше реализовать такую задачу. Приветствуются любые рассуждения на эту тему.

И, судя по всему, неудачно подобрал тег для такого вопроса.

Спасибо.

Comment: Естественно, событие: подкинули кроля, отследили процесс :) - если все  порядке, то записали данные (основное - дата, время). Вот Вам и событие - внесение даты в базу. Каждый день (минуту, секунду?) проверяются даты и запускаются процессы проверки программ действий

Comment: У меня была мысль сразу при происхождении события создавать полный набор задач с указанием дат их исполнения. То есть периодически ничего даже не придется запускать.

Comment: Так и я об этом. Событие, от которого зависят другие события. Сразу же в календарь вносятся флаги. А что сегодня будем делать? Это, то и еще 20 задач. Все уже заранее прописано... А как без периодичной проверки? Хоть раз в сутки должны сверяться даты?